# Check if class property is not null before calling any public class method

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.5

**What I have**: `Game` class (as a part of Laravel 5.5 framework)

```
class Game implements GameInterface
{
    private $currentGame;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentGame = Game::where('status', true)->first();
    }

    public function getPlayersAmount()
    {
        if ($this->currentGame)
            //fetch data & return it
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public function getPlayers()
    {
        if ($this->currentGame)
            //fetch data & return it
        else
            return null;
    }

    public function getAllStats()
    {
        if ($this->currentGame)
            //fetch data & return it
        else
            return null;
    }

    public function getTopScore()
    {
        if ($this->currentGame)
            //fetch data & return it
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

**My problem** - `if ($this->currentGame)`. I have to place it inside each method to avoid Eloquent-related Exceptions.

How can I make this check `if ($this->currentGame)` before each method call to avoid code duplicate?

`__call()` doesn't work for public methods.

My current class usage:

```
$game = new Game();
$game->getPlayers();
//and so on
```

Comment: Is `Game` itself an eloquent model? It seems so from the `Game::where(...` call. If that's the case, why are you setting `currentGame` to a different instance of `Game` and using that in those methods, rather than just using the current instance?

Comment: seems like you should fix the underling issue and not address a symptom of it in a hackish way `if ($this->currentGame). I have to place it inside each method to avoid Eloquent-related Exceptions.`  I don't use Eloquent but I have used a ORM or two in my time, perhaps if you give more information about what those are...

Comment: @Don'tPanic `Game` is an eloquent model. I made a mistake, the class might be `CurrentGame` but not a `Game`. I'll not edit, because there are some answers already.

Comment: @Tarasovych, have you seen the answers below?

Comment: @yivi yes, still looking for one which might be suitable for me

Comment: Why do the answers not suit you? Please give some more information on why they do not suit you and we can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__call` with this, you will just need to make your public functions private - and then prefix them with something unique to make sure that they are the only private functions that can be publicly callable.

Here is an example.

```
class Game implements GameInterface
{
    private $currentGame;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentGame = Game::where('status', true)->first();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if ($this->currentGame) 
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'public'.ucfirst($method)), $args);
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    private function publicGetPlayersAmount()
    {
        //fetch data & return it
    }

    private function publicGetPlayers()
    {
        //fetch data & return it
    }

    private function publicGetAllStats()
    {
        //fetch data & return it
    }

    private function publicGetTopScore()
    {
        //fetch data & return it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach dos not makes a lot of sense, in my opinion.

If your `Game` instance will depend on having a `currentGame`, it should not be possible to create the instance if `currentGame` is falsey.

Just put the verification in the constructor and throw an exception if can't be instantiated.

```
public function __construct()
  {
    $this->currentGame = Game::where('status', true)->first();

    if (! $this->currentGame) {
        throw new \Exception('Current game not available');
        // probably better if you define your own exception class
    }
  }
```

Then you just check if this works on instantiation, and if it does continue normally:

```
try { 
    $game = new Game();
    $game->getPlayers();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $game is not safe to use, do something about it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be accomplished with `__call` and `call_user_func_array`

```
class Game implements GameInterface
{
    private $currentGame;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentGame = Game::where('status', true)->first();
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $name = '_'.$name;
        if ($this->currentGame && method_exists($this,$name)) return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);
        return null;
    }

    private function _getPlayersAmount()
    {
        return "sthg";
    }

    private function _getPlayers()
    {
        return "sthg else";
    }

    private function _getAllStats()
    {
        return "also sthg else";
    }

    private function _getTopScore()
    {
        return "different one";
    }
}
```

simply we implement our functions as private with slightly different name and let them called through `__call` via `call_user_func_array`. We could also use a `switch-case` as well, however this way it's more dynamic.